# How to tree-search an html file tag with no specific type

Tags: python, html, search, tree

I'm new to Python. I wonder how to get the string from an html as following:

```
    <span style="color: blue; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 600;"> string </span>
```

I tried

```
    import lxml from html
    import requests
    page = requests.get("url")
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

but I don't know what to do next to get string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with tree searching html files because seldomly developers will move things which ends up breaking old projects. I feel its safer to go with string manipulation because if you plan it well, you won't have to reprogram it even if the developers decided to wrap your target in one more containers.

It's crazy how much you can accomplish simply with just the split function.

```
text = your_string.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
```

Here are a couple tools I made and like to use when getting a string when I know what will be before it and after it.

```
def get_str_between(s, before, after):
  # gets a substring between two strings in a string in python
  # by: Cody Kochmann
  unique="~~~~the~obvious~way~to~do~it~~~~"
  return(s.replace(before, unique).replace(after, unique).split(unique)[1])

def get_every_str_between(s, before, after):
  # returns an array of substrings between "before" and "after"
  # by: Cody Kochmann
  unique="~~~~this~is~the~obvious~way~to~do~it~~~~"
  second_unique="~~~~i~think~you'll~like~this~~~~~"
  s=(s.replace(before, unique).replace(after, second_unique).split(unique))
  out=[]
  while len(s):
    tmp=s.pop()
    if second_unique in tmp:
      out.append(tmp.split(second_unique)[0])
  return(out)

target = '<span style="color: blue; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 600;"> string </span>'

print get_every_str_between(target, ">", "</")
```

#### outputs

```
[' string ']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what does           s.replace(before, unique).replace(after, second_unique).split(unique)       mean? how does it work?

Comment: Those two functions are split up for a good reason. Pretty much there are times when you will get multiple consecutive occurrences of the beginning and end samples that you were giving so by splitting the target by all of the beginning occurrences first you can then loop through and return the split up segments that contain the end portion. :)

Comment: You don't want to rewrite that because when I originally had it like that I would have segments that were missing half the string when there happened to be a second beginning sample before it got to the end resulting in you getting the string between two beginning samples.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention the reason why it is switched to a unique string at all is because there are certain instances where one of the samples will be contained with in the other sample which renders this function useless without changing the string. It's like a quick "ignore this section because it's within the first sample"